# Option 2: Structured Product Labeling & Language - Which data to pick up?

Tags: openfda

According to the OpenFDA problem definition, it says:

Level 1: Create visualization (word cloud) of **boxed warnings**

Level 2: Develop a language model to categorize the language in the **warning sections of SPLs**

Are the data elements to be used for these two different? That is, should I pick up "*boxed_warning*" for Level 1, and "*warnings*" for Level 2 from the API output?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what's your question? Don't ask the reader of your question to Google for your problem first.

Answer (score 2):

J- Yes, that's right. Two different data elements: "boxed_warning" for Level 1, and "warnings" for Level 2.

Jess